# Java swing: image not loading

Tags: java, image, swing

I'm trying to load an image but my code continuously enters the catch statement. I followed the example provided on: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/examples/LoadImageApp.java.

I really don't understand what the programming error is here.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.FocusEvent;
import java.awt.event.FocusListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.accessibility.Accessible;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;

public class RackBuilder extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    BufferedImage img;

/**
 * Creates new form RackBuilder
 */
public RackBuilder() {
    initComponents();

    JPanel rackGrid = new JPanel(new GridLayout(42,0));

    try {
        img = ImageIO.read(new File ("alexi.jpg"));
    } catch (IOException e){
        System.out.println("Image could not be read.");
        System.exit(1);
    }

    add(rackGrid);

}    

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new RackBuilder().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Search for similar questions as this is asked about twice a week. Usually the problem is that you're not looking for the image in the right location (right file path). You're also better off using resources not files.

Comment: Note, I'm betting its a NullPointerException in that you're trying to read an image from a `null` file.

Comment: For example, `img = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("alexi.jpg"));` But again, please search on this question.